# Create an instance of the super class using a derived class instance

Tags: java, object, inheritance

So let's say there is a class A (parent class), B extends A (B is the child class). You have the object of B and you want to get the equivalent object of A from it (ie) create an object of A with the properties of A that are available in B.

You can create a function that basically creates the object of A with you feeding in the parameters. The reason I don't want to do this is that every time A is changed, I have to go in and change this function so that none of the properties are lost.

```java
Class A{
    public String Property1;
}

Class B extends A{
    public String Property2;

    public A returnAObject(){
        // returns object of A
    }
}

B object = new B("property1","property2");
A requiredObject = object.returnAObject();
```

Comment: Can you not just use a cast, ie `A requiredObject = (A) object;`

Comment: Could be that you want to use composition instead of inheritance. Instead of `B extends A`, you have `class B { public A getA(); }`.  But: No, there is no general solution to this, and it is impossible to discuss with an abstract example like this. You may get better answers if you provide a concrete use-case.

Comment: @Phil Why would you cast? Just make the assignment without the cast.

Comment: @Andreas you're right of course in that the explicit cast is redundant but hopefully it it illustrates to OP the point I was trying to make.